# Solution/Design for distributed database with time-by-time synchronization, solution for PK/FK

Tags: database, architecture, key, distributed, offline

This question is more about the architecture and idea then about code.

The issue:
Let's have a backend main DBs that stores everything.
Then we have a frontend local database (SQLLite or similar), that stores only the relevant data for user/device.

The user can create data on the frontend. However several users can create the same kind (ie. receipt) at the same time and if we would use a simple int autoincrement PK, there would be collisions on the backend.

The proposed solution is:
we use composite PK, where the PK consists of:
-autoincrement integer
-device ID
-user ID

Now, logicaly, the deviceID and userID should be FK to a table of devices and users, however for several reasons, its not practicable/possible to store all the devices/users on each frontend device, so the FK makes it problematic.

The proposed solution for this would be to ommit the FK req on the fronend and check for data integrity only on the backend, but to be honest i am not sure the risk/gain is worth it.

Has anyone been to this point and/or has some experience after deploying it?
What are your thoughts?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad,

I think the difficult problem you are trying to address is:  How can a device generate an identifier unique across all devices?  The answer in the past to that question has been to create a "Global Unique IDentifier" (GUID) or a "Universally Unique IDentifier" (UUID) that incorporates uniquely identifying information such as "device id", "timestamp", and random numbers.  The IETF standard for doing such can be found here: [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

Consequently, most database vendors provide at least a UUID() or GUID() SQL function to return one of these unique identifiers.  BTW, I don't know if [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) provides one, but I know that [SequelSphereDB](http://www.sequelsphere.com) does provide a UUID() function. The end result is that you can use these to create unique identifiers for rows.

So, instead of having a combination primary key consisting of a number, a device ID, and a User ID, have a single column CHAR(36) which stores a UUID generated on-the-fly at the time of row creation.

UUID Pros:

- Single Column
- Generated at client without the need to contact any other device
- "Guaranteed" to be unique, or at least much more so than the alternate possibilities.

UUID Cons:

- Column Storage is big:  CHAR(38).
- Generation is slow in comparison to surrogate key one-up generators.

Comment: SQLite doesn't provide a UUID or GUID function, but most programming languages now do. So you can generate the GUID in application code, then store it in a SQLite database.  You *could* create a function in C and compile it into SQLite, but I think that's usually more trouble than it's worth.